# Update multiple columns: the Username disappears

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to update my user detail with Python and SQLite.

The aim is to upgrade all the columns of my user in one go.

My code is:

```
def update():
  new_username = input("Input your NEW username:\n")
  new_firstname = input("Input your NEW firstname:\n")
  new_lastname = input("Input your NEW lastname:\n")
  new_email = input("Input your NEW email:\n")
  new_password = input("Input your NEW password:\n")
  update_customer =("""UPDATE customer SET username = ? AND firstname = ? AND lastname = ? AND email = ? AND password = ?""")
  cursor.execute(update_customer, [(new_username), (new_firstname), (new_lastname), (new_email), (new_password)])
```

I inspected the database before and after running my python function. However, the changes are not saved into the database. Nothing changes but the username that disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use AND for additional columns to be SET. Instead you separate the columns to be SET with a comma.

So you want

```
update_customer =("""UPDATE customer SET username = ?, firstname = ?, lastname = ?, email = ?, password = ?""")
```

and then a WHERE clause if not setting all rows to the same values.

As per :-

[image]

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - UPDATE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to save changes after you completed the transaction.

```
cursor = conn.cursor() # Get cursor
cursor.execute(...)    # Execute some SQL queries
# This is the line you've missed.
# You need to call this function every time you update the data in database.
cursor.commit()
```

Also, your SQL syntax for the "UPDATE" command is not correct. Use commas instead of "AND" when specifying multiple columns to be changed. Like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```